# Link's area greater than image

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I'm trying to put some images to my website which will work as a hyperlink to another part of my page. The thing is that when I use the `<a>` tag and the `<img>` tag, the `<a>` tag overextends the `<img>` on its left side making clickable a part of an area that i don't wish to be clickable. I want to keep the `<a>` tag in the limits of the `<img>`.

This is my code: (sorry but since I'm new to all this, i don't know how to post it in any other way)

```css
.firstproject {   
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: red;
   margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p><a class="firstproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img 
class="firstproject" src="front.jpg"></a></p>
```

Hope you can figure it out!

PS: I used red background so the  area would be visible and see better its extend.
PS2: I used the "youtube" address as an example of the link

Comment: You are using the same class on both the link and the image, so now you have the image increasing the link width _because_ of that. Don’t but a margin on the image, if you don’t want extra space inside the link.

Comment: I actually WANT the margin part because I want to move my pic around. any other alternative way to do the moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is simply remove the `margin-left: -100px;`. I do not know what the reason for this margin is, but if this is important for your code please let me know and ill adjust my awnser.

If you want to move the image more to the right you can use the following css:

```
position:relative;
left:25px;
```

See [CSS - Position](http://nl.learnlayout.com/position.html) for more information.

```css
.firstproject {
  background-color: red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.Secondproject{
  background-color: red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  left:50px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="firstproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="firstproject" src="front.jpg"></a>
</p>

<p>
  <a class="Secondproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="firstproject" src="front.jpg"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, margin is important as a way for me to move around my photo and put it in the desired position. I will try padding  instead of margin but something tell me that it's gonna be the same problem.

Comment: I updated my awnser to include a way to move your image.

Comment: I will give it a go and I will let you know. Thanks for the flexibility! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the margin on your `img` element and `a`. You can change the margin of the `a` element to `200px` and remove it from the `img` to get the same result without an `a` the goes out of bounds.

Also you don't need to set a width and height to the a. It's adjusting it's size to the content.

```css
.firstproject-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.firstproject-a {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="firstproject-a" href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <img class="firstproject-img" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `display: inline-block` to your `a` tag and that will give you the expected result.

To contain the image within a tag set images `width` to `100%`

```css
 
.firstproject {   
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: red;
   display: inline-block;
}
.firstproject > img {
   width: 100%'
}
p {padding-left: 100px;}
```

```html
<p><a class="firstproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img 
class="firstproject" src="front.jpg"></a></p>
```

**Edit:**
To push the `a` to right you could add padding-left to the parent of it

```
p {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I can see that there is a lack of <margin> which I used to position my image. how would you position the img of the code that you just posted? because if you use the margin element, you will get the same results as myself having the same problem :)

Answer (score -2):

To limit the size of the a tag to the extent of the defined class I'm adding `display: block` to make sure the height/width is being applied(`display: inline-block` would work too).

I have two examples in the link below, one that leaves your margin and one that keeps it, as I'm not sure of what you was looking for.

https://jsbin.com/gahunohebu/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<p><a class="firstproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img 
class="firstproject" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></p>

  <p><a class="secondproject" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img 
class="secondproject" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></p>
```

CSS:

```
.firstproject {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.secondproject {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

You can read more about CSS `display` at CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: I used margin because I want to position my photo in a certain place so I would use margin in the end. I can see that the example with the margin has that red square that I'm actually trying to avoid. so maybe can you tell me another way to move my photo and put it in a certain position without using the margin tag, hence without creating that red clickable area?

Comment: Please provide code instead of url's. Url's die over time.

Comment: @Rafael_Tsantes you need to be more specific, there is tons of ways to move elements with CSS and all might not apply in your case.

Comment: Yes you are right. Next time I will be even more specific. This time, found my solution thanks to @Granny.